# VBAT circuit explanation

Tags: stm32

I found this circuit in STM32F401VET6 schematic:

[image: VBAT]

As you can see, VBAT line has a lot of 100 nF capacitors. Is it there to mimic a battery? If yes, won't it be better to put a reverse leakage current protection diode in between?

100 nF capacitors add up to 0.8 uF, almost equal to 1 uF. Why not use 1 uF capacitors on either side of R26? Is this bigger network used for better noise filtering?

What's the use for R26? It has a value of 0 ohms.

Comment: Vbat may be either for powering a real-time clock or for some security key backup, as that functionality is not being used (if it was, there'd be a battery there), Vbat is tied to VCC by R26 (0ohm jumper). All the caps go directly to to VCC as well, I admit, the schematic's not particularly well laid out.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Those are standard decoupling caps for each VDD, and a couple more for good measure. For some reason the designer has decided to collect them all in a single location in the schematic near VBAT rather than distributing them among the supply pins they are decoupling.

R26 is there presumably so that it can be removed (or left unplaced) if battery-powered operation of the MCU is preferred.

Comment: "the designer has decided ..." - Bad decision, imo.

Answer (score 6):

*Is it there to mimic a battery?*

No they're decoupling capacitors. It is **good practice** to have a decoupling capacitor near each VDD / VBAT pin of the IC.

The decoupling caps are needed with most ICs especially digital ICs because almost all of these use CMOS logic and this logic has the habit of drawing a **current pulse** from the supply when it switches. When the IC runs at 8 MHz, this happens 8 million times a second (8 MHz). The decoupling capacitors provide a path for these pulses and stabilize the supply voltage. Without them operation of the IC would be unreliable.

*Why not one large capacitor ?*

Because then the connections to some of the pins would be longer, the decoupling would then be less effective.

R26 can simply be there for debugging purposes or to add extra supply decoupling (if needed) for the Vbat pin. Then R26 could be 100 ohms for example and that would provide increased supply filtering for Vbat.

Answer (score 3):

Those 100nF are probably decoupling capacitors. They will be spreaded over the board. There job is to supply power during short peaks in digital circuits.

R26 can be used to cut the supply during testing.

Answer (score 1):

There are two good reasons for using multiple capacitors instead of one big capacitor. One is that the capacitors can be spread around which makes the PCB track length from a switching load to one of these supply-hold-up capacitors shorter and therefore of lower impedance. That is important at high frequencies and lessens generated EMI. The second is that the overall Equivalent Series Resistance (ESR) of the terminals of all those capacitors is less than that of one big capacitor. That also gives the lower impedance and lower generated EMI benefits.

It gets worse the higher the frequencies you have kicking around in your circuit, unfortunately.